# why does <NA> result from reading a .csv file?

Tags: r, na, missing-data, read.csv

i've read in a .csv file that contains lots of missing values in the form of repeated commas (e.g. ',,,,') and get the following results for

> head(md.df[,1:8])

```
  zipcode state date_installed prog_names type size_kw appraised install_type
1   21771    MD     04/28/2016       <NA>  uir   48.36        NA   Commercial
2   21601    MD     04/18/2017       <NA>  uir   27.90        NA  Residential
3   21209    MD     10/11/2015       <NA>  uir   10.44        NA  residential
4   21014    MD     12/18/2014       <NA>  uir    8.82        NA  Residential
5   21850    MD     11/07/2014       <NA>  uir   10.20        NA  residential
6   21801    MD     12/15/2014       <NA>  uir    6.00        NA  residential
```

so what's the difference between the two NAs, and how can i set the missing values in the 4th column to the usual values in the 7th?

Comment: They're all normal missing values. Missing values in `character` or `factor` class columns print as `<NA>`, missing values in `numeric` and `logical` columns print as `NA`

Comment: As an example, run `data.frame(char = c('a', NA), fac = factor(c('a', NA)), num = c(1, NA), logic = c(TRUE, NA), stringsAsFactors = F)`

Comment: thanks...to me missing is missing, regardless of the class (do you know where this is documented?).

Comment: What you're seeing is just printing behavior. But, because vectors (or columns) can only have a single class there are variations of `NA` for each atomic class. It's documented at `?NA`. If you want, you can specify `NA_integer_` or `NA_character_`. If you look at `class(NA)`, you'll see that the default is `logical`. But it's only in very specialized circumstances that any of this info is needed or useful.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is the printing behavior for missing values *in data frames*. If you do `as.character(NA)`, or `c('a', NA)`, or just `NA_character_`, to get a vector of `character` class missing values, they will simply print as `NA`, not `<NA>`. The `<>` is added by `print.data.frame` to make the class of the coumn clearer. (Well, `print.data.frame` call `format.data.frame` with the argument `na.encode = FALSE`, which adds the `<>`)